# Send email automaticaly if a defined cell contains text

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I have to write a VBA that work automaticaly when I open the file.

The excel contains two sheets.
Sheet1 is the source.
Sheet2 is the formulas page.
The second sheet has a cell with date formulas *=today()-30* and it has an another it is a filter formula.
I want to send an email automatically if the deisgnated cell contains anything and i want to copy the list and send it as message body.

I tried different vba-s but none of them work.

I never studied programing, so I would really appreciate if somebody can help about it.

THX

I tried this.
But this macro is sends even if the cell is empty, and it doesn't contain the list as message body.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("b3"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) <> "" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
   
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Sziasztok" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Teszt email első sor" & vbNewLine & _
              "Teszt emial mésodik sor"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "xy.laszlo@sample.hu"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Küldés cella értéke alapján"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

I changed the VBA to this:

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, HtmlContent As String, i As Long, j As Long
Set rng = Worksheets("Munka2").Range("A2").CurrentRegion

HtmlContent = "<table>"

  For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<tr>"
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<td>" & Cells(i, j).Value & "</td>"
    Next
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</tr>"
    Next
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</table>"

 Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Sziasztok" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Teszt email első sor" & vbNewLine & _
              "Teszt emial mésodik sor"
              
    With xOutMail
        .To = "xy.laszlo@smple.hu"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Küldés cella értéke alapján"
        .HTMLBody = HtmlContent
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Now it can make the spreadsheet as message body.
But didn't start it automatically if B3 is contains anything.

A replaced again teh code ti this.
It's work, but i can't insert new line in the mail body.
I tried the "vbLf vbNewLine" but nothing.
The text and the spread are separeted, but the salutation isn't separeted from the next line, what ingredient the command about the spread.
[image]
What can be the solution? Where should it be insert?

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
    
     Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = Worksheets("Munka2").Range("B3")
        If (rng.Value <> "") Then
            Call SendMail
        End If
      
    End Sub
    
    Sub SendMail()
    
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, HtmlContent As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Set rng = Worksheets("Munka2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    
    HtmlContent = "<table>"
        For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<tr>"
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<td>" & Cells(i, j).Value & "</td>"
        Next j
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</tr>"
        Next i
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</table>"
    
     Dim xOutApp As Object
        Dim xOutMail As Object
        Dim xMailBody As String
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
                  
        With xOutMail
            .To = "x.y@sample.hu"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Teljesítmény lekötés értesítő"
            .HTMLBody = "Sziasztok" & vbNewLine & "Az alábbi fogyasztási helyeken a elkötött teljesítményt legyetek szívesek ellenőrízni" & vbNewLine & HtmlContent & vbNewLine & "Köszönettel" & vbNewLine & "Laci"
            .Save
            .Display
            '.Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set xOutMail = Nothing
        Set xOutAp = Nothing
        
    End Sub
```

Thanks if you can help about this.

Comment: `I have to write a VBA that work automaticaly when I open the file.` You need the `Workbook_Open` event for this and not the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: You are a victim of  `On Error Resume Next` . This statement hides all runtime errors and continues the code. Your statement `If IsNumeric(Target.Value) <> "" Then` will always throw a type mismatch error because `IsNumeric` returns a boolean and that cannot be compared to a string. As you ask the VBA runtime to continue with the next statement, the sub `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` is always executed.